# Is there any JS library to obscure string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, security-by-obscurity

I'd like to make the string manipulation as obscured as possible.

Now I wrote a small function made HEX string from the original string (the length of the result is twice as the length of the original). But even after the [uglification](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) the code is too simple to be understood by the hacker.

Is there any library which will convert the string to is self (= will not made any changes or made minor changes to the original) with very obscured code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be these tools might help you:

1. [Javascript Obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)
2. [Javascript Encoder](http://www.csgnetwork.com/directjsencoder.html)
3. [Javascript & jQuery Obfuscator Tool](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this powerful obfuscator:

http://www.js-x.com/page/javascripts__example.html?view=1109

It includes the possibility to bind Javascript to a single website (if code is downloaded, it won't work).

Here's the **live demo**: http://www.js-examples.com/page/javascripts__example.html?run=1109